# Petri-net editor

Tags: process, editor, comparison, workflow, petri-net

1-Can anybody introduce some modern Petri-net editor and compare theme?

currently I am using WoPeD.

2-Is there any UML tools that also support Petrinet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have similar problem. In this [article](http://waprile.weblog.tudelft.nl/2010/04/07/petri-net-nice-tools-and-stuff/) compared some tools for petri-net.

In my opinion the easiest to use is the [Yasper](http://www.yasper.org/) but it not open source and works Windows only. I recommend beta version [2.0b22](http://www.yasper.org/beta/). The versions 2.1b1 and 2.1b2 not works in my Windows 2003 on Virtual Box.

Currently I am using [PIPE2](http://pipe2.sourceforge.net/) because is open source, easy to use and platform independent. You may have a some problems with opening files saved in older version or other editors (such Yasper). I describe workaround in [bug tracker](https://sourceforge.net/tracker/?limit=25&func=&group_id=108734&atid=651315&assignee=&status=&category=&artgroup=&keyword=&submitter=&artifact_id=0&assignee=&status=&category=&artgroup=&submitter=dzwiedziu-nkg&keyword=&artifact_id=0&submit=Filter).

I am looking for a [editor for evaluation nets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16099215/evaluation-net-editor) and I am considering to extend [PIPE2](http://pipe2.sourceforge.net/) for support of this. Maybe someone has a better idea?

Comment: since your answer is accepted, i would also recommend adding CPNTools. its a very stable tool.

Answer (score 2):

Also, please check [Renew](http://www.renew.de/) (http://www.renew.de/).

Comment: Why I can't found any screenshot of this application?

Comment: ![Here](http://www.flickr.com/photos/34318873@N02/8722223737) it is the screenshot I took on my desktop: http://www.flickr.com/photos/34318873@N02/8722223737

Answer (score 2):

Please check GreatSPN Graphical Editor: http://www.di.unito.it/~amparore/mc4cslta/editor.html

It's amazing.

Comment: The GreatSPN is a solid visual editor with the LaTeX support

Answer (score 2):

It's probably worth asking what type(s) of nets you plan to work with (colored, stochastic, ...) and what types of import/export are desirable (PNML, ...). Snoopy is certainly relatively user-friendly and supports a variety of nets. A few editors that haven't yet been noted:

1. wolfgang (https://github.com/iig-uni-freiburg/WOLFGANG) is pretty limited but it has an easy-to-use GUI for editing; modeling is limited to manually 'walking' through transitions.
2. monalisa (http://www.bioinformatik.uni-frankfurt.de/tools/monalisa/) supports a variety of formats. The GUI for editing is straightforward.
3. tapaal (https://www.tapaal.net/) also has a straightforward GUI for editing nets.

Answer (score 1):

Snoopy is a software tool to design and animate hierarchical graphs, among others Petri nets. The tool has been developed - and is still under development - at the University of Technology in Cottbus, Dep. of Computer Science, "Data Structures and Software Dependability". 
Download it from [here](http://www-dssz.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/DSSZ/Software/Snoopy) There is also another tool called as Charlie which is an extensible software tool to analyse (extended) place/transition nets, it belongs to toolset comprising Snoopy. And can be downloaded from [here](http://www-dssz.informatik.tu-cottbus.de/DSSZ/Software/Charlie)

Both of these tools are based on Java. So you can run them on Mac, Windows and linux as well.